# Need to query results of a CTE

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, common-table-expression

I have a table that has call detail data. I've created a query to pull results based on language chosen (i.e. English, Spanish). This is accomplished by defining an AppLocationID (294 in this case)  field with the language ID.

Is there a way to run a query of the returned results of the following query?

```
select Count(*),AppLocationID, EventPayload
from IVRCallDetail_TEST 
where AppLocationID = '294' 
and (EventPayload = 'English' or EventPayload = 'Spanish')
group by AppLocationID, EventPayload
```

Comment: Can you please look this link and see how you can improve the question.https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Answer (score 1):

Your CTE specifically queries records whose `AppLocationID` is '294', and your outer query selects records from the CTE whose `AppLocationID` is '29'. Since it's not possible for a record to satisfy both of these conditions, you get zero results.

Similarly, your CTE queries records whose `EventPayload` is 'English' or 'Spanish', and your outer query selects records from the CTE whose `EventPayload` is 'CP' or 'NCP', which is another impossibility.

If you can more carefully state exactly what you're trying to achieve, perhaps I (or someone else) can help you come up with a query that gets the job done.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with this CTE, the value of your EventPayLoad column is either "English" or "Spanish"

But in your SELECT statement after CTE, you specify **(EventPayload = 'CP' or EventPayload = 'NCP').** However, the available values are only "English" and "Spanish". Definitely, it will return ZERO record to you.